# EventLog stream(real-time)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, event-log

Is there a way that I can get EventLog logs like stream(real-time) with C++, I mean to get log as soon as event happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NotifyChangeEventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363670%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: It notifies, but how can I get log message?

Comment: MSDN has an example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363677%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Basically open the event log, seek to the last record, then call NotifyChangeEventLog.  When your event is signaled, just read the event log until you get to the end.

Answer (score 0):

And for Windows Event Log, see this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about how to subscribe to events and be called back when an event is raised.